# JPQL Subquery example throws error relation "table_name" does not exist, Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpql

I am trying to implement a Subquery within a query example in Spring Boot, JPQL but getting error

> 2022-03-21 16:13:20.582  WARN 23580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
> 2022-03-21 16:13:20.582 ERROR 23580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "cases" does not exist
> Position: 30
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
> at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
> at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
> at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy464.searchCases(Unknown Source)
> at com.ericsson.smart.meter.smartmeter.service.Impl.CaseServiceImpl.searchCases(CaseServiceImpl.java:125)
> at com.ericsson.smart.meter.smartmeter.controller.CaseController.searchCases(CaseController.java:187)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
> at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103)
> at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2322)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2075)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2037)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:956)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677)
> at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2181)
> at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1204)
> at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:177)
> at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617)
> at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:128)
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90)
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155)
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143)
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159)
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
> ... 63 more
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "cases" does not exist
> Position: 30
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2674)
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2364)
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:354)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:484)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:404)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:162)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
> ... 94 more

My entity table structure is below:

```
package com.ericsson.smart.meter.smartmeter.model;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"P_CC_CASE\"", schema = "public")

public class Cases {

@Id
@Column(name = "\"CASE_ID\"")
private long caseId;

@Column(name = "\"CASE_FOCUS\"")
private String caseFocus;

@Column(name = "\"CASE_TYPE\"")
private String caseType;

@Column(name = "\"CASE_CATEGORY\"")
private String caseCategory;

@Column(name = "\"CASE_RPT_CATEGORY\"")
private String caseRptCategory;

@Column(name = "\"CASE_STATUS\"")
private String caseStatus;

@Column(name = "\"CASE_CUST_SEVERITY\"")
private String caseCustSeverity;

@Column(name = "\"CASE_EON_SEVERITY\"")
private String caseeonSeverity;

@Column(name = "\"CASE_PRIORITY\"")
private String casePriority;

@Column(name = "\"CASE_ISSUE\"")
private String caseIssue;

@Column(name = "\"CREATED_ON\"")
private Date createdOn;

@Column(name = "\"EXPECTED_RESPONSE_DATE\"")
private Date expectedResponseDate;

@Column(name = "\"LAST_CONTACT_DATE\"")
private Date lastContactDate;

@Column(name = "\"FIRST_RESPONSE_TO_CUST\"")
private Date firstResponseToCust;

@Column(name = "\"CONTACT_DATE\"")
private Date contactDate;

@Column(name = "\"CREATED_BY\"")
private String createdBy;

@Column(name = "\"ORGANIZATION_ID\"")
private String organizationId;

@Column(name = "\"QUEUE\"")
private String queue;

@Column(name = "\"CHANGED_BY\"")
private String changedBy;

@Column(name = "\"EQUIPMENT_ID\"")
private String equipmentId;

@Column(name = "\"EVENT_ID\"")
private String eventId;

@Column(name = "\"CASE_TITLE\"")
private String caseTitle;

@Column(name = "\"CASE_DESC\"")
private String caseDesc;

@Column(name = "\"SUPPORT_KEY\"")
private String supportKey;

@Column(name = "\"OBJEVENTS\"")
private String objevents;

@Column(name = "\"POD\"")
private String pod;

@Column(name = "\"CHNAGED_DATE\"")
private Date chnagedDate;

}
```

The Query I am trying to implement is as follows:

```
SELECT T1.* FROM (SELECT * FROM "P_CC_CASE" WHERE "CASE_TYPE" IN ('GAS','HEAT','ELECTRICITY') OR "CASE_TYPE" IS NULL) T1;
```

Like: `public static final String GET_CASES_BY_PARAMS = "SELECT t from (SELECT c from Cases c where c.caseType IN (:caseCategories) OR c.caseType IS NULL) t";`

```
@Query(value = GET_CASES_BY_PARAMS, nativeQuery = true)
List<Cases> searchCases(@Param("caseCategories") List<String> caseCategories);
```

I am not able to understand that the inner query is also returning a set of type Cases and so does the entire query, but when writing together gives an error. Can anyone help, how can I implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: P_CC_CASE -> this is the tablename you are looking for.

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez: Yes, but while writing JPQL we refer the Entity class not the actual Table Name. I don't think that is the problem, because I am getting the results when I am running only the inner query, i.e "SELECT c from Cases c where c.caseType IN (:caseCategories) OR c.caseType IS NULL" of type Cases.

Comment: I forget to write. \"P_CC_CASE\" this means table name is "P_CC_CASE" not P_CC_CASE. Please don't use \" this character to add string to name

Comment: No actually, I am looking for an answer for Subquery on Select clause in JPQL. Quotes I am using to match the case in Postgres DB, Tables are case sensitive here :)

Comment: Why are you using nativeQuery true then? It is not JPQL

Comment: @Query(value = GET_CASES_BY_PARAMS)
List<Cases> searchCases(@Param("caseCategories") List<String> caseCategories);

Comment: @Query(value = GET_CASES_BY_PARAMS) List<Cases> searchCases(@Param("caseCategories") List<String> caseCategories);

without nativeQuery=true this giving compilation error.

ANY HELP ON SUBQUERY ON SELECT CLAUSE IN JPA? :( 
Not getting much example for the query to implement

<select T1.* from (SELECT * FROM "P_CC_CASE" WHERE "CASE_TYPE" IN ('GAS','HEAT','ELECTRICITY') OR "CASE_TYPE" IS NULL) as T1; >

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.* FROM (SELECT * FROM "P_CC_CASE" WHERE "CASE_TYPE" IN ('GAS','HEAT','ELECTRICITY') OR "CASE_TYPE" IS NULL) T1;
```

Please just change @Column and @Entity's attribute of value to @Column("column")and @Entity("P_CC_CASE")

Table name is "P_CC_CASE" with double quota. You need to write P_CC_CASE at @Entity annotation

SELECT * FROM "P_CC_CASE" means table name is string so it can not find it.

```
package com.ericsson.smart.meter.smartmeter.model;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "P_CC_CASE", schema = "public")

public class Cases {

@Id
@Column(name = "CASE_ID")
private long caseId;

@Column(name = "CASE_FOCUS")
private String caseFocus;

...

}
```

Also there is another problem. If nativeQuery is true then you can not use jqpl.

```
@Query(value = GET_CASES_BY_PARAMS) List<Cases> searchCases(@Param("caseCategories") List<String> caseCategories);
```